# How to set hudson jobs in such a way that downstream jobs are always executed?

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, hudson-plugins

I managed to setup the hudson server, where I have 3 jobs : A, B and C.

1. The job A is build when anything is checked in the trunk
2. The job B is build after job A successfully finishes
3. The job C is build after job B successfully finishes

Job A takes about 25-35 minutes to execute, while jobs B and C are very fast (job B about 1 minute and job C about 1/2 second).

Now, because someone makes a checkin while the job A is executing, it always interrupts the process and jobs B and C are not executed.

So, is there a way to force jobs B and C to be executed after job A finishes the execution successfully?

Comment: This should be possible if you use the locks and latches plugin: have you tried that already?
http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Locks+and+Latches+plugin

Comment: @Davek No, but that page says that only locks are implemented. Is it still going to work?

Answer (score 0):

Just moving this out to an answer - as @davek says, the locks and latches plugin will work. You can make it A, B, and C part of a lock set, so that when B or C is working, A is queued. We use this in our setup to stop builds that share resources from stomping all over each other.

Caveat: There is a known bug in locks, hopefully to be fixed soon where if multiple builds are waiting on the same lock they will occasionally both start when the lock is released, rather than on holding up the other.